# How can I create a new type that extends the File type in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, types

I have this Attachment class that is supposed to be an extension of the js File type.

```js
export interface Attachment extends File {
    isVideo: boolean;
    url: string;
}

export class Attachment implements File {
    constructor(file: File) {
        Object.assign(this, file);
        this.isVideo = file.type.includes('/video');
        this.url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    }
}
```

However, it seems that the `Object.assign(this, file)` in the constructor doesn't work because it is trying to assign to readonly properties of the default File type. This ends up getting me an object with only the "isVideo" and "url" props, which is not intended.

How can I work around that? Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a class that `extends File`:

```
export class Attachment extends File {
    get isVideo() {
        return this.type.includes('/video');
    }
    getURL() {
        return URL.createObjectURL(this);
    }
}

// the constructor arguments are the same as the constructor of "File"
const attachment = new Attachment([], "filename.txt");
```

However, if the `file` is already created outside, you should forget about `extends` but store it as a property:

```
export class Attachment {
    constructor(public file: File) { }
    get isVideo() {
        return this.file.type.includes('/video');
    }
    getURL() {
        return URL.createObjectURL(this.file);
    }
}

const attachment = new Attachment(THE_FILE);
```